# How to modified the font colour and font size in sencha chart for axes text

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, sencha-touch

please help on this, how to change the font colour and font size in sencha chart for axes text

here my sample chart

http://jsfiddle.net/onlinesolution/djaydxnd/58/

```
 axes: [
   {
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['data1'],
            minimum: 0,
            maximum:20,
            fontSize:20
        }, {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'top',
            fields: ['month'],
        }
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a custom theme for this chart:

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.StackOverflow', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.theme.Green',

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent([Ext.apply({
            axisLabelBottom: {
                font: '22px Arial'
            }
        }, config)]);
    }
});
```

Later on you can use this theme in your chart configuration:

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    theme: 'StackOverflow'
    //[...] 
}
```

Here is a full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/L4x72q3j/

Here are some older but still valid details on this:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/drawing_and_charting-section-theming
and here the same based on newer ExtJs versions:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.chart.theme.Base.html#cfg-axis

Comment: thanks you @Artem Stepin its working perfectly what i expected and thanks for sharing the docs links also.

Answer (score 0):

Use label config for ExtJS 6.5.2.

```
axes: [{
  ...
  label: {
    font: '10px Open Sans'
  }
}]
```

ExtJS docs: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.chart.axis.Axis.html#cfg-label